# How to get most recent records in a group on an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following models.

```
class Candidate <  ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :accommodation
  has_many :rates, :foreign_key => :candidate_id
end

class Accommodation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rates, :through => :candidates
end

class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :candidate
  delegate :accommodation, :to => :candidate
end

class City < Location
  has_and_belongs_to_many :accommodations, :foreign_key => 'location_id'
end
```

Now I get all locations, in order to iterate them and get all locations with its accommodations and rates. The problem is that I want to have only the most recent rates of an accommodation, but grouped by a column named :supplier_id
In my view:

```
 <% acc.rates.each do |rate| %>
                  <div class="rate">
                    <div class="">
                      <h3>
                        <%= rate.promo %>
                        <small><%= rate.supplier %></small>
                        <span class="rate-price text-right"><strong><%= rate.try(:nightly_rate).try(:ceil) %></strong></span>
                        <small>€</small>
                      </h3>
                    </div>
                  </div>

              <% end  %>
```

So how can I get the most recent rates for each supplier (grouped by supplier), in a way I can eager load, otherwise performance will be too slow.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to divide this query in 2 separate queries:

```
locations = Location.includes(:accomodations)
accomodation_ids = locations.map(&:accomodation_ids).flatten
rates = Rate.by_accomodation_and_supplier(accomodation_ids)

class Rate    
  def self.by_accomodation_and_supplier(accomodation_ids)
    joins(candidate: { accomodation: accomodation_ids}).
      order(created_at: :desc).group(:supplier_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: group won't work since it needs the id. So what I tried is select('DISTINCT ON (supplier_id) *').order('supplier_id,created_at DESC'). But how do you access it inside the mentioned view? And how do you eager load?